# Vue 3 - Reactive Prop Updates Not Reflecting in Child Component Script

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to pass a reactive data as a prop to a child component in Vue 3. The data updates correctly in the child component's template, but it doesn't seem to reflect in the child component's script.
In the parent component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const someDataId = ref<number | null>()

const someFunction = (id) => {
    someDataId.value = id
}
</script>

<template>
<ChildComponent :dataId="someDataId" />
</template>
```

In the child component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const { dataId } = defineProps<{
    dataId: number | null | undefined
}>()

console.log(dataId)
</script>

<template>
{{ dataId }}
</template>
```

The `dataId` prop updates correctly in the template, but it shows as `undefined` when logged to the console.

I attempted to handle props within the `onUpdated` and `watch` functions, but the issues persist. When using `onUpdated`, the `dataId` remains `undefined`, and with `watch`, nothing even show up in the console because I guess it doesn't detect any changes. Using `nextTick` won't work either.

I appreciate any assistance or insights on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script content is executed once at the creation time, in order to see the change here you should use a watcher like below, and also don't destruct the props in order to not lose the reactivity :

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import {watch} from 'vue'

const props = defineProps<{
    dataId: number | null | undefined
}>()



watch(()=>props.dataId, (newVal)=>{
  console.log(newVal)
},{
immediate:true
})

</script>

<template>
{{ dataId }}
</template>
```

In Vue 3.3 you can destruct the props but this is still an experimental feature.

Comment: I see. The problem is from destructuring props. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome !